# How to sort an List of object arrays in ascending order

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an hibernate entity class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "grade")
    @JsonIgnoreType
    public class StudentMaster implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "grade_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer gradeId;

    @Column(name = "grade_name")
    private String gradeName;
    //getter and setter
   }
```

I have written a query that return a list of object array:
       String query = select T.gradeId, T.gradeName from grade where available = 1;

This return a list of object array

```
    List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery(query.toString()).list();
```

List is coming like

```
    [0]
     >[0] = 5001
     >[1] = "10"
    [1]
     >[0] = 5002
     >[1] = "11"
    [2]
     >[0] = 5003
     >[1] = "4"
    [3]
     >[0] = 5004
     >[1] = "18" 
      and so on....
```

I am trying to sort this in ascending order like 4, 10, 11, 18
I tried with the below code snippet but didn't work

```
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<StudentMaster>() {
        public int compare(StudentMaster s1, StudentMaster s2) {
            return s1.getGradeName().compareTo(s2.getGradeName());
        }
    });
```

can someone help me here. I am learning myself and new to coding so need help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to let DB to do its best and sort it for you. Just add order by to your query.

Update:

Since you want to order by integer value stored as string, you need to convert it to integer, using `TO_NUMBER` or specific SQL dialect syntax.
In-memory sorting  could be implemented like this :

```
new Comparator<Object[]>() {
 public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
 return Integer.valueOf((String) o1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf((String) o2[1])); 
} 
});
```

Comment: tried with this SELECT T.gradeId, T.gradeName FROM grade T WHERE available = 1 ORDER BY gradeName ASC didn't work. Same result is coming

Comment: Not sorted? Can you run the query with and without sorting  in DB client to see the difference?

Comment: Oh yes it's actually sorting by gradeName. But here gradeName is String so I am not getting the expected out put like 1,2,3,4...10,13,14, It's coming like 10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: can you suggest if there is any way to sort the **list** in java. **id** is **Integer** and **gradeName** is **String**

Comment: Use answer from Abinash if you insist on sorting in memory , but sql is faster. You can order by expression as well : order by TO_NUMBER(gradeName)

Comment: This work, I used TRY_CAST to convert. Thanks Alexander

Comment: from java side I tried something like this:

`Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
   public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
    return ((String) o1[1]).compareTo((String)o2[1]);
   }
  });`

But it didn't work. Any suggestion where I am doing wrong

Comment: Your list is of type Object[], the comparator has to be of the same type.In implementation of the comparator  get the second element, cast it to  Integer with Integer.ofString and use Integer.compareTo

Comment: return Integer.parseInt((String) o1[1] )).compareTo(Integer.parseInt((String) o2[1 ] )));
        }

Comment: My copmarator is type of object[] and in inmplementation : 

`Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
   public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
    return Integer.parseInt((String) o1[1]).compareTo(Integer.parseInt((String) o2[1]));
   }
  });`
Did't work. It's telling **can not invoke compareTo(int) on the  premitive type int**

Comment: Use Integer.valueOf instead of parseInt

Comment: It didn't help Alexander, it's throwing numberformatexception

Comment: Then not all your gradeNames are integers... Can you log the string before calling Integer. valueOf?

Comment: Oh yes one string value is there "RM"

Comment: @Alexander.Furer Try to update your answer according your conversation, thats help  other to find out the solution.

Comment: Thanks Alexander and Abinash, finally I made it work in both way.